# Use Meteronic theme in laravel project

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to design a login page in laravel using the the meteronic theme.
Can anyone help me with that.
I referred the tutorials available on web but couldn't find any relevant tutorials.

Comment: download your favorite meteronic theme HTML codes. and put it in a .blade.php file in views directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am new rk metronic. can you please share any tutorial link?